# Flutter RenderView not matching screen height

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem with flutter, where I always seem to have some sort of a black bar at the bottom of the screen(nevermind the error). I can't really tell you what caused it, because I don't know either. Long story short, I was working on a project, which I have stopped working on for 2 months, came back, and now I see this. The guy who was working on it left, and I can't ask him what caused this.

[image]

The problem doesn't seem to occur on every phone this has appeared on Poco X3 and Redmi 6, and it doesn't appear on emulators. I have looked at Flutter devtools description of root, and it says that it has a height of 763.6(logical pixels), and the device pixel ratio on Poco X3 is 2.75, which only gives me an absolute height of 2099.9(i assume that the other decimal point is not being shown, and this might be hardcoded to be 2100 somewhere in the code), which is 300 pixels off from 2400 which is the actual screen height, if i undestand things correctly. Also, before you ask, the same bug occurs regardless if I run the entire project, or a MaterialApp with Scaffold and a Container inside.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue, or knows where you can hardcode max screen height, please tell me what I should do next, because I'm at a loss of what to do.

Flutter doctor output

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1766], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at D:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (8 weeks ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc4)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\lol\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0-rc4
    • Java binary at: D:\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at D:\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • M2007J20CG (mobile) • 3dc8c919 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Windows (desktop)   • windows  • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1766]
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114
    • Edge (web)          • edge     • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.39

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

EDIT: I do have these error messages constantly popping up in my run tab, but I've no idea if these two are related.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29387): FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[1]
E/AndroidRuntime(29387): Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 29387
E/AndroidRuntime(29387): java.lang.SecurityException: Too many PendingIntent created for uid 10188, aborting Key{broadcastIntent pkg=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.contextmanager intent=act=CONTEXT_MANAGER_ALARM_WAKEUP pkg=com.google.android.gms flags=0x0 u=0} requestCode=2
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2376)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2343)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2285)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getIntentSenderWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6850)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:578)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:561)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at akdl.b(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at com.google.android.contextmanager.controller.EventHandler$AlarmSetter.c(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at ezy.d(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at faa.l(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at fkq.a(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):30)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at faa.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at ezw.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at voy.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at vpi.c(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at vpi.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):7)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at vul.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29387):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[3]
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 29434
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): java.lang.SecurityException: Too many PendingIntent created for uid 10188, aborting Key{broadcastIntent pkg=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.contextmanager intent=act=CONTEXT_MANAGER_ALARM_WAKEUP pkg=com.google.android.gms flags=0x0 u=0} requestCode=1
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2376)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2343)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2285)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getIntentSenderWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6850)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:578)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:561)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at akdl.b(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at com.google.android.contextmanager.controller.EventHandler$AlarmSetter.c(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at ezy.d(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at fby.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):9)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at fbp.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at fbm.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):1)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at feq.A(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at feq.ah(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at fep.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at ezw.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at voy.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at vpi.c(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at vpi.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):7)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at vul.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentController.incrementUidStatLocked(PendingIntentController.java:441)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentController.getIntentSender(PendingIntentController.java:165)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getIntentSenderWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:6002)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:3094)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2947)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): 
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[0]
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 29434
E/AndroidRuntime(29434): java.lang.SecurityException: Too many PendingIntent created for uid 10188, aborting Key{broadcastIntent pkg=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.contextmanager intent=act=CONTEXT_MANAGER_ALARM_WAKEUP pkg=com.google.android.gms flags=0x0 u=0} requestCode=2
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2376)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2343)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2285)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getIntentSenderWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6850)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:578)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:561)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at akdl.b(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at com.google.android.contextmanager.controller.EventHandler$AlarmSetter.c(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at ezy.d(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at faa.l(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at fkq.a(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):30)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at faa.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at ezw.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):3)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at voy.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):2)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at vpi.c(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):6)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at vpi.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):7)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at vul.run(:com.google.android.gms@220221037@22.02.21 (150400-428111784):0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29434):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Consider including [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce this. As I've said, it doesn't matter if I run the project, or a MaterialApp with a Scaffold and a Container, which means the problem is much deeper than flutter code itself, and I have no idea where too look. That's why I'm here.

Comment: try `flutter clean` and `flutter upgrage`

Comment: can you show code? or Error Log